# Rounding seconds to minutes in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 10 minutes  i.e 600 seconds for an activity. I have display the used part and remaining part in minutes. For example if 90 seconds is used then 510 seconds is left. I must display 2 minutes used and 8 minutes left. I have the following SQL

```
WITH SampleData (SECONDS) AS (  
    SELECT 90
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 510
)
SELECT roundedUpSeconds =  CEILING(CAST(SECONDS AS DECIMAL(18,6)) / 60)
FROM SampleData
```

It returns 2 & 9 minutes respectively. It does not sum up to 10. How should I solve this issue so that it sums up to 10.
I am using SQL Server.

Comment: How does your actual data look like? Is it two rows or two columns? If it's a known number of minutes and you got used seconds: `(SECONDS + 30) / 60 as used_minutes, 10 - ((SECONDS + 30) / 60) as remaining_minutes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rounded numbers to add up is tricky.  You can calculate the total sum and the cumulative sum -- then use the difference for the last value.

Your data doesn't have an ordering, so this just uses the maximum `seconds` as the last score:

```
WITH SampleData (SECONDS) AS (  
      SELECT 90
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 510
     )
SELECT (CASE WHEN seconds < max_seconds THEN minutes
             ELSE total_minutes - sum(minutes) over (order by seconds rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
        END)
FROM (SELECT sd.*,
             (SUM(seconds) OVER ()) / 60 as total_minutes,
             CEILING(seconds * 1.0 / 60) as minutes,
             MAX(seconds) OVER () as max_seconds
      FROM SampleData sd
     ) sd;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b2d14232639ad2b003d6ac99aa1daef) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @SabyasachiMukherjee . . . I don't understand your comment.  This answers the question that you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

90 seconds is 1.5 minutes and 510 seconds is 8.5 minutes which adds up to 10, but since you are using the ceiling function it round 1.5 up to 2 and 8.5 to 9, so you are not getting the right answer